# For which reasons can get_template_part's $args fail to work? (WP 5.8.1 - PHP 7.4.23)

Tags: get-template-part

I'm a big fan of the introduction of the `$args` parameter in `get_template_part()` since WP 5.5... or rather I *would be*, since I can't make it work and must still rely on `[set|get]_query_var()`.

The call to `get_template_part()` is set in an archive template, like `archive-whatever.php` and goes like this:

```
$args = array( 'my_var' => 'my_value' );
get_template_part( 'content', 'template-to-get', $args );
```

Then, as seen in every single example I've found, in **content-template-to-get.php** I do as follows:

```
if ( $args['my_var'] == 'my_value' ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But the ***stuff*** never gets done.

Which can be the possible reasons? As already stated in the title, WP version is 5.8.1 and PHP version is 7.4.23

Tahnks!

Comment: Is this actual code? I don’t see any reason this wouldn’t work. If it’s not real code, does it work if you use the example code? Are you sure the expected archive template is being used? Are other changes to the template reflected?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes it is actual code, just different var and template names but nonetheless yes the expected template is being used, also if I use `set_query_var()` in the caller template then I can retrieve it with `get_query_var()` in the target template.

Comment: `set_query_var()` is completely unrelated. So that's not really relevant. I've copied your exact code and it works completely fine. So the issue is either a mistake in the actual variable names that you're using, or whatever `// do stuff` is has an issue.

Comment: @JacobPeattie it's worse than that: it's just that I had another `$args` upper in `content-template-to-get.php` which I did not check for. So now I can go and hide myself somewhere dark and isolated. I'm really sorry for this waste of time, I appreciate your concern.